# How to enable sched_compat_yield?

Tags: linux, kernel, proc

I am not able to see the sched_compat_yield entry under /proc/sys/kernel/. How to enable this propery in the kernel (so that I can tweak it for some debugging purpose) ?

Currently Available Entries:

```
root@test ~ >ls /proc/sys/kernel/sched_*
/proc/sys/kernel/sched_child_runs_first
/proc/sys/kernel/sched_latency_ns
/proc/sys/kernel/sched_migration_cost
/proc/sys/kernel/sched_min_granularity_ns
/proc/sys/kernel/sched_nr_migrate
/proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_period_us
/proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us
/proc/sys/kernel/sched_shares_window
/proc/sys/kernel/sched_time_avg
/proc/sys/kernel/sched_tunable_scaling
/proc/sys/kernel/sched_wakeup_granularity_ns
```

I am using  `"Linux 3.3.0 #19 PREEMPT Wed May 8 14:38:18 IST 2013 armv5tejl GNU/Linux".`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to enable it because it doesn't exist any more - it was removed over two years ago by [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ac53db596cc08ecb8040cfb6f71ae40c6f2041c4) which is included in 2.6.39 and later kernels.

If you're interested in how you can figure things like that out yourself then the answer is that I used `git log -S sched_compat_yield` in a kernel checkout to look for commits which introduce or remove that string from the code.

Comment: give the fish and also teach how to get it. excellent.